# How to get the value of a radio button in a table - PHP

Tags: php, html

So I had a form that contained 30 radio buttons, 3 in a group with the same names so that the selected one out of the three would be the one that was used. What I want is for the value of that radio button to be set to a variable. It was working fine until I decided to stick it in a table. Here is what I have:

```
<form method="post"><table style="width: 99%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Questions:</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">Yes</td>
        <td style="width: 84px">No</td>
        <td style="width: 87px">Don't&nbsp;Know</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px">
<span class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">
        Q1.</label></span></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px">
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q2.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px">
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q3.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px">
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question3" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q4.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio"  name="question4" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q5. </label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q6.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question6" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q7.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question7" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q8.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question8" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question8" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1">Q9.</label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question9" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question9" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
<label id="Q1" style="height: 21px">Q10. </label></td>
        <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 84px"> 
<input type="radio" name="question10" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
<input type="radio" name="question10" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>Company name  <span class="error">*</span></p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="auto-style2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="auto-style2"><span class="auto-style2"></span>

<?php
$score1 = $_POST['question1'];
$score2 = $_POST['question2'];
$score3 = $_POST['question3'];
$score4 = $_POST['question4'];
$score5 = $_POST['question5'];
$score6 = $_POST['question6'];
$score7 = $_POST['question7'];
$score8 = $_POST['question8'];
$score9 = $_POST['question9'];
$score10 = $_POST['question10'];
$weight1 = 1;
$weight2 = 2;
$weight3 = 3;
$scoretotal1 = $score1*$weight3;
$scoretotal2 = $score2*$weight2;
$scoretotal3 = $score3*$weight2;
$scoretotal4 = $score4*$weight1;
$scoretotal5 = $score5*$weight1;
$scoretotal6 = $score6*$weight3;
$scoretotal7 = $score7*$weight2;
$scoretotal8 = $score8*$weight2;
$scoretotal9 = $score9*$weight1;
$scoretotal10 = $score10*$weight1;
$score = $scoretotal1 + $scoretotal2 + $scoretotal3 + $scoretotal4 + $scoretotal5 + $scoretotal6 + $scoretotal7 + $scoretotal8 + $scoretotal9 + $scoretotal10;
?>
```

I am well aware that there will probably be several issues with my code, I am very much a rookie. The issue is that the radio button values are not being set to those variables. I confirmed this by echoing the variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

EDIT:

Easy fix; just had to move my submit button into that form, when I added the table tags I completely forgot about the submit button :)

Code is edited.

Comment: You don't have the submit button

Comment: what is your problem exactly? I added a submit button and your form works fine.

Comment: Sigh, I knew it would be something stupid. I did have a submit button but I didn't have it as part that form. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <form method="post"><table style="width: 99%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Questions:</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">Yes</td>
                <td style="width: 84px">No</td>
                <td style="width: 87px">Don't&nbsp;Know</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px">
        <span class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">
                Q1.</label></span></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q2.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q3.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question3" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q4.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question4" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio"  name="question4" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q5. </label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question5" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q6.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question6" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q7.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question7" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q8.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question8" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1">Q9.</label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question9" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 46px" class="auto-style2">
        <label id="Q1" style="height: 21px">Q10. </label></td>
                <td>--------------------------------------------</td>
                <td style="width: 85px">
                <input type="radio" name="question10" value="5" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 84px"> 
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="2" class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td style="width: 87px" class="auto-style30">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="0" checked="true" class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
        <tr><input type="submit" name="submit"></input  ></tr>  
        </table>
        </form>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        if(isset($_POST['question1']))
        {
        $score1 = $_POST['question1'];
        echo "<br>".$score1."<br>";
        }

        $score2 = $_POST['question2'];
        $score3 = $_POST['question3'];
        $score4 = $_POST['question4'];
        $score5 = $_POST['question5'];
        $score6 = $_POST['question6'];
        $score7 = $_POST['question7'];
        $score8 = $_POST['question8'];
        $score9 = $_POST['question9'];
        $score10 = $_POST['question10'];
        $weight1 = 1;
        $weight2 = 2;
        $weight3 = 3;
        $scoretotal1 = $score1*$weight3;
        $scoretotal2 = $score2*$weight2;
        $scoretotal3 = $score3*$weight2;
        $scoretotal4 = $score4*$weight1;
        $scoretotal5 = $score5*$weight1;
        $scoretotal6 = $score6*$weight3;
        $scoretotal7 = $score7*$weight2;
        $scoretotal8 = $score8*$weight2;
        $scoretotal9 = $score9*$weight1;
        $scoretotal10 = $score10*$weight1;
        $score = $scoretotal1 + $scoretotal2 + $scoretotal3 + $scoretotal4 + $scoretotal5 + $scoretotal6 + $scoretotal7 + $scoretotal8 + $scoretotal9 + $scoretotal10;
        echo $score;
        }
        ?>
```

You have forgot to add submit button to your form and didn't check the submit button is clicked. The above works fine.